Duplicate properties when using make:entity
If I use the bin/console make:enitity to create a new entity or try and modify another already created entity it starts duplicating the properties. If I look in the databases I only see the one instance but in any of the admin or api docs that are generated, I see duplicate properties for the Entity. I created one test Entity with out the make command and it seems to work fine, not sure why this happens with that command.
